# hibernate show query execution time

Tags: hibernate

I was looking for setup hibernate or log4j to show me, how long are executed queries in hibernate, which are invoked by hql.

Till now i didn't found anything interesting.

Maybe some of you might help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 38):

There is a simple way (built in `hibernate`) to achieve it. It was fixed by [HHH-3659](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3659) in `3.5.4` and `3.6.0.Beta1`.

To go for it, use:

- logging on the package: `org.hibernate.stat` at least on `DEBUG` and
- set hibernate property: `hibernate.generate_statistics=true`

Afterwards all the `SQL`s will be logged including the row count fetched and the time the query execution took.

Moreover if interested, it provides statistics on queries. To have them exposed via `JMX` and see them using `JConsole`, you can use `Hibernate JConsole plugin`, available on: http://hibernate-jcons.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hi Peter, It worked for me but I had to change the log4j's level to trace on org.hibernate.stat to get that working. Thanks for your solution

Comment: That worked for me!
In logback.xml: <logger name="org.hibernate.stat" level="INFO"/>
In hibernate.properties: hibernate.generate_statistics=true

Comment: It does work for JDBC queries sent by org.hibernate.loader.Loader, but not those sent by org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher (lazy loading).  The easiest solution was to configure logging on DEBUG for "org.hibernate.*" and see which query is executed at which log timestamp.

Comment: I tried this, one drawback is that it reports statistics at the end of the session.  If you do many things in one session you can't determine the performance of each. For example "1436424992 nanoseconds spent executing 14 JDBC statements;"

Comment: It is showing HQL and not SQL. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: `org.hibernate.stat` has to be of `DEBUG` level.

Answer (score 8):

With Spring Boot you can use these two rows in your `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

Comment: Works for me in spring boot 2.7.18. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To log queries with its execution time to log file you may try [Craftsman Spy JDBC Driver](http://zer0.free.fr/craftsman/spy.php) which do exactly same things and has simple [integration with Spring](http://java.dzone.com/articles/logging-spring-jdbc-and).

Another way is to using [Spring Insight](http://www.springsource.org/insight) which shows JDBC/Hibernate calls and many more details.

Related links:

- [How to install Spring Insight](http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2010/10/web-application-profiling-spring.html)
- [How to setup filters](http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/2.5/devedition/htmlsingle/devedition.html#using-filtering-trace-details)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a custom solution, you can use the AOP and add an around advice around the hibernate session class if you are executing native queries.