# How to monitor each query execution time with hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, log4j

In hibernate,I'm using show_sql property=true and as well hibernate.generate_statistics=true .But this doesnt helped me lot. Awaiting for the suggestions and thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Guys! Thanks for ur quick response. Please help me in doing it with Hibernate-JConsole. For your information, I have an appllication running on Mule Server ,Intellij IDE with hibernate and Spring configured. Can u please provide me detailed steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring hibernate show query execution time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656452/spring-hibernate-show-query-execution-time)

Answer (score 2):

Do these steps :-

Change the **log4j's** level to trace on **org.hibernate.stat**

logging on the package: **org.hibernate.stat** at least on INFO and

set hibernate property: `hibernate.generate_statistics=true`

Afterwards all the SQLs will be logged and the time the query execution took.

It provides statistics on queries. If you want you can expose them via JMX and see them using JConsole (http://hibernate-jcons.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I wanna do it with Hibernate JConsole . For your information, I have an appllication running on Mule Server ,Intellij IDE with hibernate and Spring configured. Can u please provide me detailed steps. I have gone through the reference which u provided but it doesnt helped me much

Comment: Answer Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656452/spring-hibernate-show-query-execution-time#18204269

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Library [datasource-proxy](https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy). Which will log the exact SQL query with appended parameters and execution time as well. This will help you better I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the JConsole Hibernate plugin:
http://hibernate-jcons.sourceforge.net/usage.html

Using this you will be able to see all the queries being performed as well as running times.

Answer (score 0):

First step sperate Query building and query execution in two methods. And then apply @Loggable annotation on execution method. You can read the details of it [here](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-loggable.html). Which will print the amount of time taken by method execution.