# Java @schduled & hibernate sessions delay

Tags: java, hibernate, session, try-catch, spring-transactions

i have a function with a fetch query which is run from 2 places
- First place its called sequentially which takes 2 secs to run
- 2nd place is when `@Scheduled` job is run , the same query takes 30 secs to run.

Can someone help me with this issue , this is a big performance hit to the application.
Does the `@Scheduled` java functionality pick up a different hibernate session due to which a delay is induced when running the query? `@Scheduled` function is called every 5secs to pick up a job from DB queue based on which the query is executed

```
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5*1000)
    @Transactional
    public void dataScheduled() throws MessagingException, IOException, InstanceNotFoundException, AttributeNotFoundException, MalformedObjectNameException, ReflectionException, MBeanException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    /*some code


    */
    getNotification();
}
    getNotification(){
    //some query
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Do you check query execution time for example like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18204269/11733759 maybe code before `getNotification` is slowe?

Comment: i've profiled the application and checked, its exactly the query thats taking time when autoFLush takes place. Thats how the framework is designed. I tried to overwrite flush mode to manual however it overrides to autoflush in the end. however the same code runs totally when its called outside of the @scheduled