# Spring Batch: Azure SQL Performance is inconsistent

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, spring-batch, azure-sql-server

I have a spring batch application that uses Azure SQL server as a backend, I am using Hibernate to update the database.

I am reading the data from CSV file using FlatfileReader & writing into Azure SQL Server using ItemWriter as mentioned below

Below is my Hibernate configuration

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    ">
    
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.entity" />

    <bean id="itemWriter" class="com.demo.batch.jobs.csv.Writer" >
        <constructor-arg ref = "hibernateItemWriter"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="irusDataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.demo.*</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- DATA SOURCE -->
    <bean id="irusDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver85.database.windows.net:1433;database=sqldb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;" />
        <property name="username" value="ddddd" />
        <property name="password" value="`JNp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:cvs/input/students.csv" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="student" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.demo.batch.mapper.StudentMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<batch:step id="starterJob">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk
                reader="cvsFileItemReader"
                processor="itemProcessor"
                writer="itemWriter"
                commit-interval="100">
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

Below is the ItemProcessor

```
import com.demo.entity.Student;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;

public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<Student, Student> {

    @Override
    public Student process(Student item) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("Processing..." + item);
        //Thread.sleep(50);
        return item;
    }

}
```

Below is the ItemWriter

```
public class Writer implements ItemWriter<Student> {
    private HibernateItemWriter<Student> hibernateItemWriter;

    public Writer(HibernateItemWriter<Student> hibernateItemWriter) {
        this.hibernateItemWriter = hibernateItemWriter;

        System.out.println("Hibernate Writer instance is created..: " + hibernateItemWriter.hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    //@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void write(List<? extends Student> list) throws Exception {
        hibernateItemWriter.write(list);
    }
}
```

The CSV file has 6k records, at times it takes **4mins** to complete the job

[image]

other times, it takes **15mins**
[image]

> How could the simple code executed on the same VM will have different
> performance results? Is this something due to Azure SQL Performance
> being inconsistent? How to ensure that it will always have 4mins
> execution time?

**Stats for 4mins execution**

```
19100 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
15127700 nanoseconds spent preparing 200 JDBC statements;
4103544900 nanoseconds spent executing 200 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
2099567900 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 100 entities and 0 collections);
```

**Stats for 15mins execution**

```
19400 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
15668300 nanoseconds spent preparing 200 JDBC statements;
13671456600 nanoseconds spent executing 200 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
6881730800 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 100 entities and 0 collections);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple inserts of 6K records taking this much time does not sound ok. You can try enabling hibernate statistics (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656452/hibernate-show-query-execution-time)) and you might get idea of how much time hibernate is spending in other internal tasks and executing SQLs. You will see something like below

```
2021-11-08 21:58:18 - Session Metrics {
    4918700 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    20 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    300 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

Also it is worth checking the network latency between VM running the code and the SQL Server ( for e.g., if they are in different regions you might be incurring big penalty in interacting with database in network round-trip especially if your SQLs are not being batched)

Comment: Updated the question with stats, query execution and flushing takes more time. However I don't know why. can you suggest?

Comment: what is the difference between  query execution and flushing?

Comment: So in your case the major time is being spent in VM itself consuming CPU and memory. Query execution is the time for running the query - flushing is how Hibernate checks the objects and it's relations for dirtiness ( for what has changed). Plus looks like you are not using SQL Batching.

Comment: "13671456600 nanoseconds spent executing 200 JDBC statements" - can happen only if your SQL's are not batched and SQL are being executed one by one.

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/performance-improve-use-batching for impact and best practices related to batching for Azure SQL.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way for me to convert the code to use batch processing? I am using Hibernatewriter.Write method